# How can I use the additional functions of AvS_FastSimpleImport in the backend?

Tags: import, avs-fastsimpleimport

The AvS_FastSimpleImport provides some handy functionality (for example auto-creating drop-down attributes). But it is aimed on constructing your own array.

There are use cases where shop owns should be able to insert data using the upload function in the backend.

It is possible to seamlessly integrate this functionality into the backend?

I guess we basically just have to exchange the import adapter somewhere?

Comment: Simple customizations of the CSV format should be possible by rewriting `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Adapter_Csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Question.
It should be possible, but I haven' tried it yet. I would take the following steps:

- Split the classes in my module in two each - (1) one with the general stuff which can be used via backend too (for example better error messages, advanced category handling, ...), and (2) the other one for the array-specific stuff. The second one (2) should extend the first one (1).
- Create Rewrites for the core ImportExport classes with the newly created classes (1)
- Add additional backend controls for the new options which need configuring, for example a selection of the attributes for which new option values should be created. This can be in the system configuration.

Caveats:

- Take different versions into account - 1.6, 1.7, 1.8 (CE)
- Heavy testing needed, ideally create Unit Tests

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this will be possible, I've currently got code in the works that allows you to pass regular CSV-files to the adapter with all the added functionality (https://github.com/ho-nl/AvS_FastSimpleImport/commit/ff9a27fa40240e1e7dea22bb4ec1b6e6aca9c818).

To use this adapter from the backend, you'll need to update the XML, for an example take a look at: https://github.com/ho-nl/AvS_FastSimpleImport/commit/d38ecc614f26e0b6ab9dfe29adcb54e67034cc3f#diff-1

Edit September 11 2013: the option to use CSV-files is currently in the master branch. Category-import has been tested thoroughly.